# Show that a linear operator is a projection.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, functions, operator-theory

Say I have the following linear operator,

$$S(g)(y)=g(y)-\int_0^1g(x)dx$$

on the space $C([0,1])$ where $g$ is a function therein, and that I want to show that $S$ is a projection, that is to say that $S\circ S=S.$

Here is what I have done so far. The only thing to do, it seems, would be to try and directly compute $S\circ S=S$,

$$S(Sg)(y)=Sg(y)-\int_0^1Sg(x)dx$$

$$=g(y)-\int_0^1g(x)dx-\int_0^1\left( g(y)-\int_0^1g(x)dx\right)dx$$

$$=g(y)-\int_0^1g(x)dx-\int_0^1 g(y)dx+\int_0^1\int_0^1g(x)dxdx$$

$$=-\int_0^1g(x)dx+\int_0^1\int_0^1g(x)dxdx$$

Now I understand that the second part of this sum should end up being equal to $g(y)$ so that we obtain,

$$S(Sg)(y)=Sg(y)$$

However I am not sure what to do with the double integral in order to get this.

Comment: You can also see geometrically that the operator is a projection onto hyperplane of functions of zero mean.

Comment: As chandu has pointed out in his solution, it is not really a double integral. Once you integrate the first time, it is a constant, which you then integrate over $[0,1]$, recovering the same number,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
S(Sg)(y)&=Sg(y)-\int_0^1Sg(x)dx \\
&=g(y)-\int_0^1g(x)dx-\int_0^1\left( g(x)-\int_0^1g(y)dy\right)dx \\
&=g(y)-\int_0^1g(x)dx-\int_0^1 g(x)dx+\int_0^1\int_0^1g(y)dydx \\
&=g(y)-\int_0^1g(x)dx-\int_0^1 g(x)dx+\int_0^1g(y)dy \\
&=g(y)-\int_0^1g(x)dx \\
&=Sg(y)
\end{align}

Comment: Should the last integral in the third last line not be, $\int_0^1g(x)dx$, as opposed to being with respect to $y$?

Comment: as it is a definite integral, x or y would be dummy variable

Answer (score 0):

The operator $Qf = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$ is easily verified to satisfy $Q^{2}f=Qf$. Therefore $S= I-Q$ satisfies $S^{2}=I-2Q+Q^{2}=I-2Q+Q=I-Q=S$.